# How can i make image in full screen without to lose some parts of image on screen

Tags: flutter, image

to display image according to it's original size i do the following

```
Image.file(File(fileCreated!.path)),
```

to display image to fit height and width (full screen) i do the following

```
Image.file(File(fileCreated!.path),fit: BoxFit.cover,height: double.infinity,width: double.infinity,),
```

ok it is now in full screen but i noticed there is some missing parts of the image contents is no longer visible on screen like 20 pixel from width and height , i know flutter do it for keeping the image quality the same. but How i ignore that behavior

How could i display image in full screen so the whole image parts is visible on screen ?

i tried with following

```
 height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
```

whatever i change the height. the width will be auto changing too, even if i did not change the width !!!!

but same result

[image]

edit :
full parent

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      body: Image.file(File(widget.imageFile,),fit: BoxFit.cover,height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MediaQuery`, but I will prefer using `LayoutBuilder` on top widget. Also check the parent widget if it is having padding/margin.

```dart
Image.file(
  File(fileCreated!.path),
  fit: BoxFit.fill,
  height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
),
```

Comment: i tried with  MediaQuery .. it is the same result . there is missing parts

Comment: please chick my screenshot i added

Comment: can you include more about top level widget, A sample snippet will helps better

Comment: i have edited it . please chick . it is only Scaffold

Comment: on Material ? how about `BoxFit.fill`, or does the image itself contains some padding?

Comment: OMG yes IT WORK with BoxFit.fill .. thanks a lot .. please edit your answer to accept it :D

Comment: Seems like `.cover` pointed this issue with *As small as possible while still covering the entire target box.To actually clip the content, use clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge alongside this in a FittedBox* and `.fil` *Fill the target box by distorting the source's aspect ratio.*

Comment: i see .........

Comment: any idea How could i collocate the missing part using .cover?

Comment: i am deadly need to know how

Comment: Might be focused on device & image aspect ratio